# Is there any solution to the Error 300008 and Error 3006 message besides retry?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been trying to create a character (after login) and all of my attempts give me a reply of `Error 300008` and `Error 3006`.  Both saying Request timed out.

Is this just because the servers are currently experiencing high volume of requests? Or is there something more on my end to resolve first?

Note: I am already logged in.

**EDIT:**

Related errors: `Error 3003` and `Error 37`

Comment: Launch date means an uber amount of requests: expect to receive timeouts frequently. If you're logged in there are no problems on your end -- any Internet issues on your end would cause you to be automatically logged out.

Comment: Have the same problem, so it's not just you there is stucked. My guess is the servers..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Blizzard's twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/BlizzardCS) has linked to [this article](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-connection-troubleshooting) to try to work around it.

However, that all assumes the problems are local to you.  Given this is the D3 launch, I think it's reasonable to assume that's not the case for 99% of us.  In other words, just keep retrying unless you think you may have a legitimate network problem on your end.

Comment: Thank you, After waiting  30+ minutes, I was able to get in.